# Subsite URL Changes to main site name in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, url

I have a subsite at xyz.sharepoint.com/sites/xyz/ab

When I access the URL i reach the site but then the URL in the address bar changes to xyz.sharepoint.com and because of this I cannot refersh the page or save it as a bookmark.

The site is a custom build hosted in SharePOint Online.

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: You have to check your custom App what it is doing....

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMVP  This is the error i see when I debug the network Refused to display 'https://portal.office.com/SuiteServiceProxy.aspx?upn=CSTQURESR%40CORP.JTI.C…arepoint.com%2F&returnUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fjticorp.sharepoint.com%2F&Silent=1' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

Answer (score 0):

It was indeed the JavaScripts that was changing the URL.